# Support authentication and TLS options in mongo kafka sink connector

Tags: mongodb, mongo-connector

I am using offical mongo kafka sink connector jar.I have added mongo-kafka-connect-1.7.0-all.jar in strimzi connect cluster plugins path. I don't see any option for authentication and  TLS mentioned in the documentation to secure mongo connection.Please suggest me if I am missing something.
If no, then do we have any other  connector jar available for which supports authentication and TLS for securing mongo connection.

documentation link which I am following:
https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/current/sink-connector/configuration-properties/